# hashi_vault don't work through Web Application Firewall

Tags: url, ansible, hashicorp-vault, web-application-firewall, ansible-vault

I want to retrieve a vault secret with Ansible using the hashi_vault module which doesn't seem to work through a WAF.

The hashi_vault module work when the vault server is mapped to the root url (https://address/) in the WAF but when we use a custom path (https://address/vault) the Ansible playbook return this error : "Invalid Hashicorp VaultToken Specified for hashi_vault lookup"

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: set variables
      set_fact:
        vault_token: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          SOMETOKEN
    - name: get Configuration token from Vault
      set_fact:
         vault_result: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=secret/data/all/default/token token={{ vault_token }} url=https://address validate_certs=False' ) }}"
    - name: parse result
      set_fact:
         TOKEN: "{{ vault_result.data.token }}"
      register: TOKEN
    - name: show result
      debug:
        msg: "{{ TOKEN }}"
```

I'd love to find a way to keep my custom url (https://address/vault) and get my secret !

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to your WAF, it's just a variable issue...

Try something like that:

```
- name: get Configuration token from Vault
  set_fact:
    vault_result: "{{ lookup('hashi_vault', 'secret=secret/data/all/default/token token=' + vault_token + ' url=https://address validate_certs=False' ) }}"
```